# retrieve data from soap object via kvm serializable and store in array

Tags: android, web-services, serializable, ksoap

I have a web service in php which retrieves data from a database and i consume this web service in my android application. the problem is that i need the data retrieved in another android activity, i have tried using a for loop to retrieve the data from the kvm serializable and save it in an array and send the array to another activity using intents. I am getting the following problem

```
03-28 17:48:37.629: E/AndroidRuntime(956): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-28 17:48:37.629: E/AndroidRuntime(956): java.lang.ClassCastException: org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive cannot be cast to java.lang.String
03-28 17:48:37.629: E/AndroidRuntime(956):  at com.example.testwebser.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:87)
03-28 17:48:37.629: E/AndroidRuntime(956):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
03-28 17:48:37.629: E/AndroidRuntime(956):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
03-28 17:48:37.629: E/AndroidRuntime(956):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
03-28 17:48:37.629: E/AndroidRuntime(956):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-28 17:48:37.629: E/AndroidRuntime(956):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-28 17:48:37.629: E/AndroidRuntime(956):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
03-28 17:48:37.629: E/AndroidRuntime(956):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-28 17:48:37.629: E/AndroidRuntime(956):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-28 17:48:37.629: E/AndroidRuntime(956):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-28 17:48:37.629: E/AndroidRuntime(956):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-28 17:48:37.629: E/AndroidRuntime(956):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

It is giving me error in line 87, which is

```
myArr[i]= (String) ks.getProperty(i);
```

this is part of my main activity
try {

```
                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                System.out.println("response: " + androidHttpTransport.responseDump);
                SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();

                KvmSerializable ks = (KvmSerializable)envelope.getResponse();
                if(result!=null){

                    String[] myArr=new String[7];
                    for(int i=0;i<ks.getPropertyCount();i++)
                    {


                      myArr[i]= (String) ks.getProperty(i);

                    }
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, View_menu.class);
                    intent.putExtra("menu", myArr);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
```

I have no idea how to retrieve the data.please help :)

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to solve it by using the code below in my main activity

```
Bundle basket = new Bundle();
                basket.putString("mname",mname);
                basket.putString("mdesc", mdesc);
                basket.putString("mprice", mprice);
                basket.putString("mtime", mtime);
                basket.putString("mavail", mavail);
                basket.putString("mpromo", mpromo);
                Intent goToViewMenu = new Intent(MainActivity.this, View_menu.class);
                goToViewMenu.putExtras(basket);
                startActivity(goToViewMenu);
```

and to retrieve in the display class

```
if(bundle !=null)
        {

          String strdata = bundle.getString("mname"); 
          String strdata1 = bundle.getString("mdesc");
         txt_name.setText(strdata);

         }
         else
         {

         }
    }
```